# Task control with Mercurial harder since incorrect commit messages cannot be changed

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I used to use SVN, and I could track the task by adding the task number in the commit message, for example:

```
-m "Task34: done something"
```

This is used to track all the changes relating to a certain task. Any errors (which do happen) in the commit summary can be modified.

However, in Mercurial the commit summary cannot be changed, and hence I cannot follow my approach of task control. Is there a better approach for task management? or is there a way to change the commit summary?

Comment: "hg rollback"?  Maybe it's me, but changing a commit summary seems to violate the principle of what a "commit" means.

Comment: You should not change the commit message in Mercurial, you should consider that an immutable part of your commit. You *can* but that requires you to rewrite the repository from scratch (there are tools to do this though), but that makes the new repository incompatible with clones you have of it before you rewrote it. Are you hosting your software online somewhere, like BitBucket, Codeplex, Kiln?

Comment: no I am not, just on my server

Comment: Why did you edit the Subversion changeset descriptions? I mean, with the commit message in your question here, when and why would you ever edit that? Is suddenly "Task34" something else? If you can tell us more about the workflow you used, perhaps we can suggest better alternatives.

Comment: I track my tasks with their task id. Every commit is mapped to a task. When reviewing code from a particular task, a svn log search is done for "Task n". All the commits filtered out are reviewed. I recently made a typo and my reviewer could not find my commits. eg. I wrote in "Taks34". With svn, I simply could modify that log. With mercurial, I cannot do that. Any other workflow suggestion is welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is built around the idea of a ***immutable*** history.  Every change is strictly the addition of a new changeset.  For example, removing something is done by adding the inverse (using the `backout` command) so you have a record of both the bad code and its removal in history (as opposed to no record of it in history).

The model is that of a scientist writing in his or her logbook in pen on numbered pages, recording both successes and failures.

That said, the base mercurial functionality isn't going to make revising commit messages, even if they've never been been pushed, because that goes against the model.  There are, however, other ways to keep revising code until you're happy with it.  You can use Mercurial Queues, which are mutable overlays, which can themselves be immutably versioned.

However, were I you I'd just adopt a workmode that embraces the immutability.  Your putting the issue id in the commit is great -- just keep doing that and do any updates or corrections in subsequent changesets with the same id in the description.

Then you'll be able to do something like:

```
hg log --keyword Task34
```

Which will instantly show you all the changes related to that Task ID, and if some of them are "backed out previous attempt, taking another stab at it using foobaz module" that's good practice not a flaw.